# How to use PHP in Javascript functions

Tags: javascript, php, function

Can I please have some help in using a PHP variable in some Javascript code.
i want to use php code in javascript function how to use php scripts in javascript function
for example i want to use php code in this javascript function

```
function rank()
{
<?php echo'hello';?>
}
```

Comment: It probably won't work because PHP runs on server side. If you still want interaction you need to use Ajax.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using like this

```
function rank()
{
 var someVariable = "<?php echo 'hello';?>";
}
```

Comment: now how to show my function i have using rank() but not worked

Comment: what you are asking, I did not get it.

Comment: change `echo'hello'` to `echo 'hello'`

Answer (score -1):

try this (better & shorter)

```
function rank()
{
    var variable="<?='hello';?>"
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use like this:

```
function rank()
{
  var rankVar;
     rankVar = "<?php echo'hello'?>";
}
```

Comment: It is same as what i have answer.

Comment: Even I posted at same time but when i posted after that i got to see your answer :)